# Different pages for showing different fields of a single node in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is it possible to elegantly do this? The idea is, a node of content type "project" has a lot of fields, its url is something like `node/5`. I want to show some of the fields on that page, and others on `node/5/extra`, kind of an "extended" page that the user only loads if he is interested in that content (lots of images, in my case, that would slow down the main node page considerably).

I tried the [Display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module, unsuccessfully (it seems it's not really meant for doing what I want). I also saw [this blog post](http://mearra.com/blogs/juha-niemi/drupal-7-custom-node-view-modes), which explains how to add a custom display mode to a content type (other than the Default and Teaser ones that come by default), but I can't get it to work the way I want to either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could create a view having the node ID as a default argument from URL. Then you can choose which fields to show or hide